# An array and a map output multiplication

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

So I have this code:

```
# include all functions from the math and numpy library
from math import *
from numpy import *
from functools import reduce

# definition of the function Sc see Table 2 for details
def Sc(Dd, ki, ei, Ci, T=298.15, sigma=0.072, gmax=10, g=1+1e-11, inc=1.01):
    # calculate the A parameter in equation 9
    A = 8.69251e-6*sigma/T
    # returns H(xi) as defined in equation 10
    xi = map(lambda x: x if x < 1 else 1, Ci*(g**3.0 - 1.0)/ei)
    #    xi = Ci*(g**3.0 - 1.0)/ei
    # calculates the dot product of the hygroscopicity and solub. vectors in Eq. 10
    k = dot(ki, ei*xi)
    # defines the function given by equation 9
    S = lambda D, Dd, k, A: (D**3.0-Dd**3.0)/(D**3.0-Dd**3.0*(1.0-k))*exp(A/D)
    # implementation of a pairwise max function; f(2,3) returns 3
    f = lambda x,y: x if x > y else y
    # returns 1 when g > gmax otherwise return the larger value S(g*Dd) or S(g*Dd*inc)
    return 1 if g > gmax else reduce(f,[S(g*Dd,Dd,k,A), \
Sc(Dd,ki,ei,Ci,T=T,sigma=sigma,gmax=gmax,inc=inc,g=g*inc)])
```

When I execute the defined function with these parameters:

```
Sc(100e-9, array([0.6,0.2]), array([0.5,0.5]), array([inf,0.1]))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
k = dot(ki, ei*xi)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'map'
```

I know it's selfexplanatory, but how to avoid it? Is there any way to perform

```
k = dot(ki, ei*xi)
```

without error?

Thanks for help!

Comment: `map` is not executed immediately. You need: `array(list(map(lambda x: x if x < 1 else 1, Ci*(g**3.0 - 1.0)/ei)))`

Comment: Thanks! :) That works as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to evaluate the result of `map` explicitly in Python 3.
For example:

```
xi = np.array(map(lambda x: x if x < 1 else 1, Ci*(g**3.0 - 1.0)/ei))
```